# Web.Content calling API service and merging pages with List.Transform started to fail

Tags: powerquery

I created PowerBI report which which is connecting to data source via API service. Returning json contains thousands of entities. API service is called via Web.Content function. API service returns always total record count and so we are able to calculate nr. of pages which has to be called to obtain whole dataset. This report is displaying data from our servicedesk app, which is deployed on many servers and for many customers and use Query parameters to connect to any of these servers.

Detail of Power query is below.

Why am I writing here. This report was working without any issue more than 1,5 year but on August 17th one of servers start causing erros in step Pages where are some random lines (pages) with errors - see attached picture labeled "Errors in step Pages". and this is reason that next step Entities (List.Union) in query is stopping refresh and generate errors with message:

- Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type List. Details: Value=[List] Key=requests

What is notable

API service si returning records in the same order but faulty lists are random when calling with same parameters
some times is refresh without any error

The same power query called on another server is working correctly , problem is only with one specific server.

This problem started without notice on the most important server after 1,5 year without any problem.

Here is full text power of query for this main source, which is used later in other queries to extract all necessary data. Json is really complicated and I extract from it list of requests, list of solvers, list of solver groups,.... and this base query and its output is input for many referenced queries.

[Errors in step Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYNUN.png)

```
let
BaseAPIUrl = apiurl&"apiservice?", /*apiurl is parameter - name of server e.g. https://xxxx.xxxxxx.sk/ */
EntitiesPerPage = RecordsPerPage, /*RecordsPerPage is parameter and defines nr. of record per page - we used as optimum 200-400 record per pages, but is working also with 4000 record per page*/
ApiToken = FnApiToken(), /*this function is returning apitoken value which is returning value of another api service apiurl&"api/auth/login", which  use username and password in body of call to get apitoken */

GetJson = (QParm) =>  /*definiton general function to get data from data source*/
    let 
        Options = 
        [   Query= QParm,
            Headers=
            [
                Accept="application/json", 
                ApiKeyName="apitoken", 
                Authorization=ApiToken
            ]
        ],
        RawData = Web.Contents(BaseAPIUrl, Options),
        Json    = Json.Document(RawData)
    in  Json,

GetEntityCount = () =>  /*one times called function to get nr of records using GetJson, which is returned as a part of each call*/
    let 
        QParm = [pp="1", pg="1" ], 
        Json  = GetJson(QParm),
        Count = Json[totalRecord]
    in  
        Count,

GetPage = (Index) =>  /*repeatadly called function to get each page of json using GetJson*/
    let 
        PageNr  = Text.From(Index+1),
        PerPage   = Text.From(EntitiesPerPage),
        QParm = [pg = PageNr, pp=PerPage],
        Json  = GetJson(QParm),
        Value = Json[data][requests]
    in  Value,

EntityCount = List.Max({ EntitiesPerPage, GetEntityCount() }),  /*setup of nr. of records to variable*/
PageCount   = Number.RoundUp(EntityCount / EntitiesPerPage),  /*setup of nr. of pages */
PageIndices = { 0 .. PageCount - 1 },
Pages       = List.Transform(PageIndices, each GetPage(_) /*Function.InvokeAfter(()=>GetPage(_),#duration(0,0,0,1))*/),  /*here we call for each page GetJson function to get whole dataset - there is in comment test with delay between getpages but was not neccessary*/
Entities    = List.Union(Pages),
Table       = Table.FromList(Entities, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
```

I also tried another way of appending pages to list using List.Generate. This is also bringing random errors in list but
it is bringing possibility to transform to table in contrast with original way with using `List.Transform`, but other referenced queries are failing and contains on the last row errors

When I am exploring content of faulty page/list extracting it via Add as New Query there are always all record without any fail.....

```
Source = List.Generate(    /*another way to generate list of all pages*/
    ()  =>  [Page = 0, ReqPageData = GetPage(0) ],
    each [Page] < PageCount, 
    each [ReqPageData = GetPage( [Page] ),
            Page =  [Page] + 1 ], 
    each [ReqPageData]
),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), /*here i am able to generate table from list in contrast when is used List.Generate*/
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1"), /*here aj can expand list to column*/
#"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Expanded Column1", {"Column1"}) /*here i try to exclude errors, but i dont know what happend and which records (if any) are excluded*/
```

[Extracting errored page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSfF.png)

and finnaly I am tottaly clueless not able to find the cause of this behavior on this specific server. I tested to call pages which are errored via POSTMAN,  I discused this issue with author of API service and He also tried to call this API service with all parameters but server is returning every page OK, only Power query is not able to List.Transform ...

I will be grateful and appreciate any tips or advice or if somebody solved the same issue in the past ....

Kuby

Comment: What happens if you just remove the rows with errors on them in powerquery. It won't solve your source problem I put would let you use the data you did get

Comment: Hi, behind the one row with error coud be hundreds or thousend lines from servis desk. I use paging parameter of API service to call page by page and then union all partial list togehther. removing rows with error will remove half of dataset. But in this step of poqer query transfomation is not possible to remove errors :(

Comment: Transform errors to a null list {} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, problem described in this issue was caused by "corrupted" content of returning json. The provider of core system informed me that they found bug and after fixing on the side of servisdesk is everything OK again. I tried to find problem in Power query and problem was in servisdesk. :(

Answer (score 0):

No, each error line of list in step List.Transform coud by extracted as new query and there are all records from one page OK. hmmmm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).